# Iterating through array on params in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im stuck in a very simple problem. I am receiving an array of parameters in my view and want to iterate over the values.

This is the print of my params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dfOQVuXlQriII3akiGCSuMIf4i2B8c1/OX02nd6Dhy0ZKzHkhiXxlcXKCJAMFHw0vhtNKKVYuLHFo22LGsy6UQ==", "album"=>{"name"=>"asdasd", "photos_media"=>["[{\"id\":\"a245b724845f447eb63dfbaa3fba173669b55fcdf7fb55fb634707ff0c1c\",\"filename\":\"BWT_eUmU.jfif\",\"content_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"size\":56060},{\"id\":\"1bfb4188a126079f5069c5204f8df1c7169d0464f488385ef1f8d081fcda\",\"filename\":\"drafts.png\",\"content_type\":\"image/png\",\"size\":6029}]"]}, "commit"=>"Save Album"}
```

My album_params are like this:

```
  def album_params
    params.require(:album).permit(:name,  photos_media: [])
  end
```

And my form:

```
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="form-group row" >
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="">Name:</label>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="form-group row" >
      <div>
        <div class="progress" id='progress-bar' style='display:none;'>
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%"><h6>Loading...</h6>
            <span class="sr-only" id='progress-bar-text'></span>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="">Add or drag photos here:</label>
        <%= f.attachment_field :photos_media, multiple: true, direct: true, presigned: true %>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I iterate over photos_media? If I do a print on it like this:

```
 logger.debug("******SIZE*** #{album_params[:photos_media].size} ")
```

It says the size is 1. Like a big string.

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Look at your params, it is really a string `"photos_media"=>["here goes long string with an array inside"]`. Add code of the form, from which you get the params

Comment: Im editing and adding the view

Answer (score 1):

As Vailisa says, `photo_media` contains an `Array` with one element that is a `string`:

```
"photos_media"=>["[{\"id\":\"a245b724845f447eb63dfbaa3fba173669b55fcdf7fb55fb634707ff0c1c\",\"filename\":\"BWT_eUmU.jfif\",\"content_type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"size\":56060},{\"id\":\"1bfb4188a126079f5069c5204f8df1c7169d0464f488385ef1f8d081fcda\",\"filename\":\"drafts.png\",\"content_type\":\"image/png\",\"size\":6029}]"]
```

Specifically, that `string` is a JSON `string`.

To parse that on the backend, you can try:

```
@photo_media_ary = JSON.parse(album_params[:album][:photos_media][0])
```